# How to build and run xmr-stak-amd on linux

Tags: cryptonote, mining

CPU: FX-6300
GPU: RX 470 4GB Asus Strix

I am having a hard time running xmr-stak-amd on my xubuntu machine.  I run cmake and then make in the folder, but it appears to be no way to run the miner itself?  Any help would be appreciated.  It feels as though I am missing something very obvious even though I've read several guides on the subject.  I'll answer any questions in order to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if there is a folder called "bin" in the same folder that your compiled the miner. If there is, cd to it and see if the binary is there.